# Fill array with range values but not if cell is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range full of data that I want to put into an array. However, there are blank cells in this data and I do not want to include them in my array.

I have created the below but It is not working, I've tried to put a `msgbox "if has been triggered"` into the `IF` statement and no msgbox has appeared when running this which says to me the `IF statement isn't actually triggering.

```
Dim rngAB As Range: Set rngAB = wsWeights.Range("AB4:AB" & wsWeights.Cells(Rows.count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row)
Dim arr() As Variant

k = 1
For Each cell In rngAB
    If cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
        arr(k, 1) = cell.Value
    k = k + 1
    End If
Next
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: If the `MsgBox` within the `If` is not being shown, that suggests that column `AB` of your worksheet is completely empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point here is what do you mean by "blank"? A cell which is `Empty`, for example, is different from one which contains `vbNullString`.

Only you will know exactly what *blank* means for your project, but some common ways of checking are:

```
If IsEmpty() Then ...
If Len(value) > 0 Then ...
If Len(Trim(value)) > 0 Then ...
If Trim(value & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then ...
```

In terms of your code, you do need to dimension your array before you populate it. One way, but by no means the only way, of achieving your task would be as follows (I've assumed the `IsEmpty()` case):

```
Dim r As Long
Dim data As Variant, n As Variant
Dim col As Collection
Dim arr() As Variant

'Read sheet data into array.
With Sheet1
    data = .Range(.Range("AB4"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp)).Value2
End With

'Acquire the non-empty array indexes.
Set col = New Collection
For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
    'We're using the IsEmpty() function.
    If Not IsEmpty(data(r, 1)) Then col.Add r

    'Uncomment any of the below if you prefer to use them instead:
    'If Len(data(r, 1)) > 0 Then col.Add r
    'If Trim(data(r, 1) & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then col.Add r
Next

'Dimension array to size of non-empty list.
ReDim arr(1 To col.Count, 1 To 1)

'Populate the array
r = 1
For Each n In col
    arr(r, 1) = data(CLng(n), 1)
    r = r + 1
Next
```

Comment: FWIW - If a cell is empty (i.e. has nothing in it, no formula, no value) it will pass a test of `If cell.Value = vbNullString Then` (and, similarly, fail a test of `If cell.Value <> vbNullString`) because the cell value of `Empty` will be cast to a string of `""` prior to the comparison being performed, and a string of `""` is the same as `vbNullString`.

Comment: @YowE3K, yes fully agree. I didn't go into Formula, CSV, etc cases - it's a good point.

Comment: But the big question is ... why doesn't the OP's code hit the Msgbox which they said they placed inside the `If`?  That implies that all cells in the range are empty, which is the opposite of the sort of problem that people normally have.  That's what has me stumped.  (Another of life's little mysteries.)

Comment: @YowE3K, I know, it's really strange. And if they were all empty, his `rngAB` definition wouldn't have worked as he expected. Nothing a sneaky peek at some sample data wouldn't cure!

Answer (score 1):

So this should work:

```
Sub FillArrayNoBlanks()
Dim ws As Worksheet, Cell As Range
Dim rngAB As Range, k As Long: k = 0
Dim arr() As Variant

Set ws = Worksheets(1)
With ws
    Set rngAB = .Range("AB4:AB" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row)
End With

For Each Cell In rngAB
    If Cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(k)
        arr(k) = Cell.Value
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

So whats missing are some definitions, but most importantly the array does not define its size just by putting in some values. In VBA you have to use `ReDim` to define the size of the `Array`, `Preserve` is to keep the values already in the `Array`. If you dont really need it for something else, i wouldnt recommend using a 2 dimensional array, because you can only `ReDim` the last dimension of an `Array`.